# Azure Function - System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm running the following `insert` code within my azure function into an azure sql server 2014 database:

```
    private static void Command(SqlConnection sqlConnection, string query)
    {
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection?.Close();
        }
    }
```

and getting the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Here are the chains of dependencies it's using:

[image]

**How do I run a simple sql command from my app? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Same problem for me on production environment with Windows Server 2016, .NET Core 2.1.6. I don't have any direct reference to nuget package of System.Data.SqlClient v4.6.0. And so I don't know how that have been updated and also how to remove or revert it...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you don't need the latest stable version `4.6.0`, simply revert to `4.5.1` would work.

Otherwise the workaround is to load the assemblies on our own. Right click on Function project and `Edit <FunctionAppName>.csproj`, add items below to copy related assemblies to output dir.

```
  <!-- For publish -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.6.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- For local debug -->
  <Target Name="CopyToBin" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.6.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
  </Target>
```

There's an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568) tracking this assembly reference problem.

Comment: i tried with 4.8 still it also throw same exception but 4.5.1 working fine

Comment: VS on Mac - this works but you'll need change the backslash to a slash.

Answer (score 4):

I have downgrade the System.Data.SqlClient to 4.6.0 then it worked for me

Comment: Also had to add nuget package reference to function app project csproj as well.

Comment: Joey, what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this with an Azure Functions instance that had somehow been configured to use .NET Core 3.0.0. I changed the configuration setting `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` from `beta` to `~2`. After I restarted it, it went back to using 2.0.x and this error went away.

Answer (score 3):

in my case i got resolved this by changing runtime version 3 to 2 under FunctionAppSettings in Azure's FunctionApp

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EF Core, v2.1.4 seems to work.