# Azure functions runtime exception, the type initializer for system data sqlclient excetion, Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll'

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.0, sqlclient

I am using **aspnet core 3.0 and azure function v3-preview with system.data.sqlclient version 4.7.0**
When i try to run azure function(on both service queue trigger and time trigger) it gives below error :

The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.

I tried solutions from below links but didn't work:
1. [Azure Function - System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952409/azure-function-system-data-sqlclient-is-not-supported-on-this-platform)
2. https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/9

I tried using **"Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" for aspnetcore 3.0** But still the same exception occurs while running Azure function on Azure portal.

Please help !

Here is csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3-preview</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.30-beta2" />
    <PackageReference Include="runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- For publish --><!--
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\\microsoft.data.sqlclient\1.0.19249.1\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  --><!-- For local debug --><!--
  <Target Name="CopyToBin" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.data.sqlclient\1.0.19249.1\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
  </Target>-->

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\\system.data.sqlclient\4.7.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\system.Data.SqlClient.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyToBin" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.7.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\system.Data.SqlClient.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Could you please share the code in your azure function ?

Comment: @HuryShen I have added code files; Its working locally but not on Azure portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me by adding below code in csproj file :

```
<Target Name="PostPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
  <Exec Command="move $(PublishDir)\runtimes $(PublishDir)\bin" />
</Target>
```

This line should be taking care of that: 
`<Exec Command="move $(PublishDir)\runtimes $(PublishDir)\bin" />`

reference : [github](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1370)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your azure function meet these criteria in this [link](https://dev.to/azure/develop-azure-functions-using-net-core-3-0-gcm).

And here is a [workaround](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1370#issuecomment-545655510) provided by others, add the following to your .csproj:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(OutDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PostPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="copy $(PublishDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(PublishDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Added this line also                                                                                                   <Exec Command="move $(PublishDir)\runtimes $(PublishDir)\bin" />                                      i will try to remove deps.json lines as per github solution

Comment: Finally only this line worked :                                                                                
  <Exec Command="move $(PublishDir)\runtimes $(PublishDir)\bin" />                                 Thanks